# Enter text Only on HTML input text field and Disallow Numeric or Symbols at the time of Entering,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to allow users to enter text only in HTML input text, where disallowing
users to enter numbers or symbols at the time of entering?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, try this instead:

```js
function alphaOnly(event) {
       var value = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
       var pattern = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z]/i);
       return pattern.test(value);
    }

    $('#input').bind('keypress', alphaOnly);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label>
       
       <input id="input" type="text">
    </label>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this quite simply with a little regex:

```html
<form action="#">
<input type="text" 
pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, But i need to perform the operation at the time of user entering the values in the text box. Preventing them entering numeric values or symbols , before reaching for the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript you can do something like this:

```html
  <form action="#">
  
  <!-- with pattern attribute -->
<input type="text" 
pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"/>
    
    <!-- with javascript helper function -->
<input type="text" onkeyup="(function change(v){
                               let result = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]+$').test(v.value)
                            console.log(result);
                            return result;
                               })(this)"/>
</form>
```